# Swing Timer in Netbeans GUI

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer, gui-builder

This is my first Swing application so I used NetBeans GUI Builder. 
There is a Start button to start simulation(two loops: the outer by days and the inner by hours). At each iteration the loop should pause. When you click on the Stop button simulation should stop. I tried to ways:
1)

```
private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            while(presentDay <= numberOfDays){
                jTextField2.setText(Integer.toString(presentDay));
                for(; presentTime <= 18; presentTime++){
                    jTextField6.setText(Integer.toString(presentTime));

                    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

                    for(Event ev: schedule[presentDay-1].day){
                        if((presentTime <= ev.getTimeFinish()) && (presentTime >= ev.getTimeStart())){
                            res.append(ev);
                            ev.setStatus(1);
                        }
                    }
                    currentEvent.setText(res.toString());
                    // Pause should here
                }
                presentTime = 9;
                presentDay++;
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

2) Add Timer in main class constructor

```
public PlanningSystem() {
    initComponents();
    ...
    timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            while(presentDay <= numberOfDays){
                jTextField2.setText(Integer.toString(presentDay));
                for(; presentTime <= 18; presentTime++){
                    jTextField6.setText(Integer.toString(presentTime));

                    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

                    for(Event ev: schedule[presentDay-1].day){
                        if((presentTime <= ev.getTimeFinish()) && (presentTime >= ev.getTimeStart())){
                            res.append(ev);
                            ev.setStatus(1);
                        }
                    }
                    currentEvent.setText(res.toString());
                    // Pause here
                }
                presentTime = 9;
                presentDay++;
            }
        }
    });
}
private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    timer.start();
}
```

But both ways did not work. I hope you help solve this problem.
And sorry for my English :)

======================================================================
After editing :

```
private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
if(presentDay <= numberOfDays){
    jTextField2.setText(Integer.toString(presentDay));
    Timer tim = new Timer (5000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(presentTime <= 18){
            jTextField6.setText(Integer.toString(presentTime));
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            for(Event ev: schedule[presentDay-1].day){
                if((presentTime <= ev.getTimeFinish()) && (presentTime >= ev.getTimeStart())){
                    res.append(ev);
                    ev.setStatus(1);
                }
            }
            currentEvent.setText(res.toString());
            presentTime++;
        }
        }
    });            
    tim.start();
    presentTime = 9;
    presentDay++;
}
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you simply need to replace, first two loops with `if` blocks, like `if ( presentDay <= numberOfDays ) {  if ( presentTime <= 18 ( ) {  DO WHAT YOU DOING, HERE  } }`. This should work. Since you be calling this action after a specified time, as described while initializing the `Timer` object reference.

Comment: @nIcEcOw I replace loops with if blocks, but now timer works only for if(presentDay <= numberOfDays) branch. Not for presentTime. Maybe I should use two Timer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is the problem. You are incrementing `presentDay` to `numberOfDays` the first time your timer is called. After that, nothing is ever going to change again.

I believe (though because of the partial code you posted, I can't be sure) that if you take out the while loop, it will work as you desire

Edit: (Better understanding of what you're doing)

Using two timers is wrong. Just use one timer, and update both your presentDay and presentTime there.

```
Timer tim = new Timer (5000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           presentTime++;
           if (presentTime == 24) {
             presentTime = 0;
             presentDay++;
           }
           //times how now been set
           //update your GUI here

        }
}
```

Comment: I did it, but now timer works only for presentTime. Also I used two Timer(for presentDay and presentTime), but they work separately.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand can you clarify?

Comment: I edit post, hope it will help you to understand me. In my last code presentTime is incremented with pausing. And it is right. presentDay is not incremented because of `if` statement. But if I replace `if` on `while` then presentDay immediately takes the value of numberOfDays.

Comment: great! Click my answer as the solution?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps, though, in order to mimic the use of two loops, I used a `BubbleSort` algorithm. Though as already stated, removal of single while loop will do that thingy. Since in this case it is working as expected, though how will it work, in case of a long list is doubtful. Else you can look at [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerExample {

    private JLabel [] labels;
    private static final int TOTAL_VALUES = 5;
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private JButton startButton;
    private JButton stopButton;
    private Timer timer;

    private int [] values = {
        5, 10, 20, 2, 8
    };
    private int pass;
    private int i;

    private ActionListener timerActions = new ActionListener () {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent ae ) {
            if ( pass <= TOTAL_VALUES - 1 ) {
                System.out.println ( "Pass: " + pass );
                for ( int i = 0; i <= TOTAL_VALUES - 1 - pass; ++i ) {
                    System.out.println ( "i: " + i );
                    try {
                        int left = Integer.parseInt ( labels [ i ].getText () );
                        int right = Integer.parseInt ( labels [ i + 1 ].getText () );
                        System.out.println ( "[ " + i + " ] " + left + " [ " + ( i + 1 ) + " ] " + right );
                        if ( left > right ) {
                            String value = labels [ i ].getText ();
                            labels [ i ].setText ( labels [ i + 1 ].getText () );
                            labels [ i + 1 ].setText ( value );
                        }
                    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
                        ex.printStackTrace ();
                    }
                }
                ++pass;
            }
        }
    };

    public TimerExample () {
        pass = 1;
        i = 0;
    }


    private void displayGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel ();
        contentPane.setLayout ( new BorderLayout ( GAP, GAP ) );

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel ();
        createLabels ( topPanel );
        contentPane.add ( topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel ();
        startButton = new JButton ( "Start" );
        startButton.addActionListener ( new ActionListener () {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent ae ) {
                if ( !timer.isRunning () ) {
                    timer.start ();
                }
            }
        } );
        stopButton = new JButton ( "Stop" );
        stopButton.addActionListener ( new ActionListener () {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent ae ) {
                if ( timer.isRunning () ) {
                    timer.stop ();
                }
            }
        } );
        bottomPanel.add ( startButton );
        bottomPanel.add ( stopButton );
        contentPane.add ( bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END );

        frame.setContentPane ( contentPane );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform ( true );
        frame.setVisible ( true );

        timer = new Timer ( 1000, timerActions );
    }

    private void createLabels ( JPanel contentPane ) {
        labels = new JLabel [ TOTAL_VALUES ];
        for ( int i = 0; i < TOTAL_VALUES; ++i ) {
            labels [ i ] = new JLabel ( "" + values [ i ], JLabel.CENTER );
            contentPane.add ( labels [ i ] );
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                new TimerExample ().displayGUI ();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater ( runnable );
    }
}
```